# Crystal report viewer giving me error : "Invalid Argument provided. Failed to open a rowset."

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

i am having a crystal report , that is to be filled with stored procedure, but when i put any parameter of procedure in .rpt file it is giving me error like

> "Invalid Argument provided. Failed to open a rowset."

my code is as below :

```
public void GroupwiseRegistrationReport()
{
    SqlConnection connection;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    connection = gen.con;
    string SP = "";
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    SqlTransaction transaction = null;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        if (rblReportFrom.SelectedValue == "0")
        {
            SP = "SPGroupwiseIndustriesEM1Report";
        }
        else
        {
            SP = "SPGroupwiseIndustriesEM2Report";
        }

        ValueData = new ArrayList();

        ParameterData[0] = "@fromdate";
        ValueData.Add(txtTotalBetweenFrom.Text.ToString().Trim());

        ParameterData[1] = "@todate";
        ValueData.Add(txtTotalBetweenTo.Text.ToString().Trim());

        ds = gen.FunSearch_Trans(ParameterData, ValueData, SP, transaction, command);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (rblReportFrom.SelectedValue == "0")
            {
                repdoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~\\admin\\Reports\\Groupwise-EM-I-Registration-Report.rpt"));
            }
            else
            {
                repdoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~\\admin\\Reports\\Groupwise-EM-II-Registration-Report.rpt"));
            }
            repdoc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);

            configureCrystalReports();
            crvMSMEReportViewer.ReportSource = repdoc;
            //Response.Buffer = true;
            //Response.ClearContent();
            //Response.ClearHeaders();

            //repdoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "Exported Report");

            tablereportviewer.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            tablereportviewer.Visible = false;
            message("No Records Found.");
        }
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tablereportviewer.Visible = false;
        error.LogError(ex);
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Am i missing something or what i cant figure it out please help me..

And which is the best way to deal with crystal report ,is it  with using dataset or directly stored proceure?

**Update**

i changed my code like below but now is giving me message like :"Missing parameter values.
 ". but i have only two parameter to pass which are "@fromdate" and "@todate"

here is a code snippet :

```
  doc = new ReportDocument();
        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~\\admin\\Reports\\Groupwise-EM-II-Registration-Report.rpt"));
        doc.SetDatabaseLogon(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pwd"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverName"], "databaseName", false);
        doc.SetParameterValue("@fromdate", txtTotalBetweenFrom.Text.ToString());
        doc.SetParameterValue("@todate", txtTotalBetweenTo.Text.ToString());
        crvMSMEReportViewer.ReportSource = doc;
        crvMSMEReportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
      if (Session["ReportDataSet"] != null)
         {
           crvAccountReportParameter.ReportSource = (ReportDocument)Session["ReportDataSet"];
         }
    }
private void LoadReport()
{
    doc = new ReportDocument();
    DataSet dsData = null;
    dsData = objAccountReportBAL.getAccountRegister(txtTotalBetweenFrom.Text.ToString(), txtTotalBetweenTo.Text.ToString());            
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("CrSalesReport.rpt"));      
    doc.SetDataSource(dsData.Tables[0]); 
    Session["ReportDataSet"] = rptDoc;
    crvAccountReportParameter.ReportSource = rptDoc;
    crvAccountReportParameter.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: please refer updated code. i cant figure it out what is going wrong. can it be a server rights problems?

Comment: still it is not working. is there any other way to deal with crystal report ?